# change windows phone 6 profile [normal,silent,vibrate] not taking effect on the main screen?

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

i have problem that i need to switch on my application the phone profile to silent [normal ,vibrate ,**Silent**, Automatique , Loud]

so i found solution to modify the "ActiveProfile" registry key like this

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("ControlPanel\\Profiles", true);
registryKey.SetValue("ActiveProfile", "Silent");
registryKey.Flush();
registryKey.Close();
Registry.CurrentUser.Flush();



PhoneSoundState.SNDFILEINFO sNDFILEINFO = default(PhoneSoundState.SNDFILEINFO);
sNDFILEINFO.sstType = PhoneSoundState.SND_SOUNDTYPE.None;
PhoneSoundState.SndSetSound(PhoneSoundState.SND_EVENT.All, ref sNDFILEINFO, true);


int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
int WM_WININICHANGE = 0x001A;

SendMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0xF2, 0);
```

the code work 100% when i in to setting -> profile . i found the profile switched 
but when going to the main screen it steel like it was [Normal] 
event when i restart the phone ,not refreshed to the new value [Silent]

here is demonstration about after executing the code . images :

[In Setting ] https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGEHl.png

[In the main screen] https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFfJs.png

so what i miss to do  and thank you

Comment: possibly there are more changes in the registry. I use ssnap by s-k tools (freeware) for such deterministis analysis. Just run ssnap before you manually change the profile and make anoth snapshot after the change. Then compare both snapshots to find the differences. In worst case the setting is written and read from a special location (ie NVRAM, Radio module or SIM card) and reflected to registry on every boot. If so, you are lost. The reg key is not a standard MS Window Mobile registry key (not documented), possibly it is OEM dependent.

Comment: i found another key that need to be changed and it work